# Can I call ANOTHER JS FILE and return DATA (here: string) from it with JQUERY AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently experimenting around with a webframework (ZURB Foundation 6.4) and Im just figuring out how to implement my own JS. 
Because Im unfortunately working at an office machine without admin privileges, its a huge pain in the a** to get some apache/php server running to test out the implementation of JQUERY AJAX calls.

Therefore, I just want to test the front-end implementation by calling another JS file with jquery ajax. This file shall just return a string. This is merely to have some dumb file to call via AJAX and return data from it, so I can figure out how to implement this later on when I have an actual backend to work with.

Is this possible? I already tried to call a JS file but it doesnt seem to work. I dont get any data returned from the file. Since the implementation of the ajax call is a bit different from how I would normally do it, I find it hard to figure out whether Im doing something wrong in writing out the call, or if its just not possible to call another JS File via jquery AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that you can't call another local file without uploading it to the server.

If you are using npm you can try for testing purposes fully worked and easy to use Json Server (google it).

> Created with <3 for front-end developers who need a quick back-end for
>   prototyping and mocking.